# Select2 not working - No results found

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-select2

I'm using Select2 and constantly get "No results found" even though I my JSON-array fetches results. Any thoughts? The selectbox is working properly otherwise.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#supplier').select2({
  ajax: {
  url: 'lagraGet.php',
  data: function (params) {
     var query = {
         search: params.term,
         type: 'GET',
         what: 'suppliers'
      }
      return query;
   }
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

JSON respons:

```
{"results":[{"id":1,"text":"Studio 27 HB"}],"pagination":{"more":false}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in datatype. I added: 
`dataType: 'json',` to the list in ajax and it works fine.

```
$('#supplier').select2({
 ajax: {
  url: 'lagraGet.php',
  dataType: json,
  data: function (params) {
     var query = {
         search: params.term,
         type: 'GET',
         what: 'suppliers'
      }
      return query;
   }
  }
 });
```